# SQL Query : Alter columny value if columnx value is greater, less or equal

Tags: mysql, database, compare

I have a column named `average` and a column named `result` in my sql table. I want to alter column result value to "Pass" if average is greater or equal to 35, else result value to "Fail".

Can anyone tell me what will be sql code for performing these actions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case-when` in the update statement something as

```
update table_name
set 
result = 
case when `average` >= 35 then 'Pass' else 'Fail' 
end ;
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer and it worked !

Can you please tell me how to find max 2 number of 3 number. In the same table where average and result are there, some more columns are num1, num2, num3, and max1, max2

I want to find largest of num1,num2,num3 and store the max in max1...
And second largest of num1,num2,num3 and store the max in max2...

Can you please tell me the code for this ?

Comment: I would recomand to add a new question with the table structure with some sample data and desired output.

Comment: Here I have asked the question. Plese reply...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29167268/sql-query-find-max-2-of-3-number-and-store-it-in-another-column