# SQL Query : Find max 2 of 3 number and store it in another column

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table named result having column `name, rollno, sub1, sub2, sub3, max1, max2` etc.
`sub1, sub2, sub3` will store marks obtained. I want to find max of `sub1, sub2, sub3` and store it in `max1` and find second max of `sub1, sub2, sub3` and store it in `max2`.

Example

```
sub1  sub2  sub3      max1  max2
10     15    20        20    15
40     10    25        40    25
33     64    51        64    51
```

Can anyone tell me the sql code for this ?

**UPDATE**

Instead of storing the maximum number to `max1` and second maximum to `max2`, I want to divide maximum number and second maximum number by 2 and want to store it in `average` column without storing it in `max1` and `max2`.

Means I don't want two extra column `max1` and `max2` to store maximum and second maximum, then add it and divide it by 2 then store it in `average`. I want to do average direclty.

Please update the code.

Example

```
sub1  sub2  sub3   average

10     15    20     17.5   ( (Maximum + Second Maximum)/2 )
40     10    25     32.5   
33     64    51     57.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following

```
mysql> create table test (sub1 int, sub2 int , sub3 int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)

mysql> insert into test values (20,30,40),(10,40,50),(30,10,20);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.08 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test ;
+------+------+------+
| sub1 | sub2 | sub3 |
+------+------+------+
|   20 |   30 |   40 |
|   10 |   40 |   50 |
|   30 |   10 |   20 |
+------+------+------+
```

So to get the `max1` and `max2` from the columns you can use `greatest` function.

```
select * ,
greatest(sub1,sub2,sub3) as max1 , 
greatest(
 case 
  when greatest(sub1,sub2,sub3) = sub1 then 0 else sub1 
 end,
 case 
  when greatest(sub1,sub2,sub3) = sub2 then  0 else sub2 
 end, 
 case 
  when greatest(sub1,sub2,sub3) = sub3 then 0 else sub3 
 end
) as max2 from test ;
```

This will give you something as

```
+------+------+------+------+------+
| sub1 | sub2 | sub3 | max1 | max2 |
+------+------+------+------+------+
|   20 |   30 |   40 |   40 |   30 |
|   10 |   40 |   50 |   50 |   40 |
|   30 |   10 |   20 |   30 |   20 |
+------+------+------+------+------+
```

You can use this for update command as

```
update table_name
set 
max1 = greatest(sub1,sub2,sub3),
max2 = greatest(
 case 
  when greatest(sub1,sub2,sub3) = sub1 then 0 else sub1 
 end,
 case 
  when greatest(sub1,sub2,sub3) = sub2 then  0 else sub2 
 end, 
 case 
  when greatest(sub1,sub2,sub3) = sub3 then 0 else sub3 
 end
)
```

To get the average of max1 and max2 and update as

```
update table_name
set 
`average`
= ( 
   greatest(sub1,sub2,sub3)+
   greatest(
    case 
      when greatest(sub1,sub2,sub3) = sub1 then 0 else sub1 
    end,
    case 
      when greatest(sub1,sub2,sub3) = sub2 then  0 else sub2 
    end, 
    case 
      when greatest(sub1,sub2,sub3) = sub3 then 0 else sub3 
    end
     )
)/2 ;
```